# Merging variables with include_vars fails with "failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'NoneType' and a 'AnsibleMapping'"

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to merge several vars files with the same dictionary structure as follows:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    dir: "vars"
    hash_behaviour: merge
```

contents of vars directory:

```yaml
# test1.yml:
test_var:
  test1: foo

# test2.yml:
test_var:
  test2: bar
```

What I'm expecting is a variable structure like this:

```yaml
test_var:
  test1: foo
  test2: bar
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'NoneType' and a 'AnsibleMapping':
    null
    {"test2": "bar"}
```

There is not a lot of information available in the docs, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: The `null` on the first line make me think that one of the two files in the directory _vars_ is actually empty.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε it looks like the problem is `test_var` being undefined before starting to try and merge. I posted my solution below which  seems to tackle this problem.

Comment: Mhm, you're right indeed. But the right solution is then your usage of `vars` to define `test_var: {}`, you didn't had to resort to using a loop.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I tried that, but for some reason it still wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have it working now by initializing the `test_var` variable and using a loop instead of including a directory:

```yaml
- include_vars:
    name: test_var
    hash_behaviour: merge
    file: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'vars/*', wantlist=True) }}"
  vars:
    test_var: {}
```